# How to use boost::iostreams::null_sink as std::ostream

Tags: c++, boost

I want to make my output verbose/non verbose based on a flag given at runtime. My idea is, to construct a std::ostream dependent of the flag, such as in:

```
std::ostream out;
if (verbose) {
    out = std::cout
else {
    // Redirect stdout to null by using boost's null_sink.
    boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::null_sink> null_out{boost::iostreams::null_sink()};

    // Somehow construct a std::ostream from nullout
}
```

Now I'm stuck with constructing a std::ostream from such a boost streambuffer. How would I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Using Standard Library

Just reset the `rdbuf`:

```
auto old_buffer = std::cout.rdbuf(nullptr);
```

Otherwise, just use a stream:

```
std::ostream nullout(nullptr);
std::ostream& out = verbose? std::cout : nullout;
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aad0e8675dafdc9)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char**) {
    bool verbose = argc>1;

    std::cout << "Running in verbose mode: " << std::boolalpha << verbose << "\n";

    std::ostream nullout(nullptr);
    std::ostream& out = verbose? std::cout : nullout;

    out << "Hello world\n";
}
```

When run `./test.exe`:

```
Running in verbose mode: false
```

When run `./test.exe --verbose`:

```
Running in verbose mode: true
Hello world
```

### Using Boost Iostreams

You /can/ of course use Boost IOstreams if you insist:

> Note, as per the comments, this is strictly better because the stream will not be in "error" state all the time.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddbdc0c666850baf)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

int main(int argc, char**) {
    bool verbose = argc>1;

    std::cout << "Running in verbose mode: " << std::boolalpha << verbose << "\n";

    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink> nullout { boost::iostreams::null_sink{} };
    std::ostream& out = verbose? std::cout : nullout;

    out << "Hello world\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution works as I intended. Is this code portable to other platforms? And why wouldn't the null_sink work in this case?

Comment: Null sink works but has non-standard (link) dependencies (it has strictly more cost). Use it when you want to e.g. statically template some code on a null-stream (`boost::iostream::stream<null_sink>`).

Comment: Here's the equivalent `null_sink` example: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddbdc0c666850baf)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already have boost as dependency, so I don't mind using it here, too.

Comment: nullptr has the disadvantage that the badbit is set.  Try adding `std::cerr << out.bad() << std::endl;` to the last line of each example to see it.

Comment: @Eyal Good point! If the writing code polls the status of the output stream periodically rsp. uses stream exceptions, and it should do either, this could cause problems.