# How to cast to a shared_ptr<std::ofstream> from std::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink>>

Tags: c++, boost, iostream, boost-iostreams

I have a member that is a `shared_ptr<ofstream>`.

In a specific case, I want to suppress the output, and making the stream a `boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink>`. Should do what I want.

I would prefer to avoid the `ofstream(nullptr)` suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141745/), it doesn't compile when wrapped in `make_shared()`.

I'm open to other null `ofstream` `shared_ptr` suggestions, but it needs to be cross platform.

Initializing it with an output (non suppressed) works:

```cpp
InputReader::InputReader(std::string filepath2, std::string filepathmain){
    this->thestreamstruct.themainWriter = std::move(std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(filepathmain.c_str()));
}
```

In the suppressed initializer, I declare the null sink stream `shared_ptr` instead of initializing the `ofstream`, and then want to cast this to an `ofstream` and assign it to the member:

```
InputReader::InputReader(std::string filepath2, Model* amodel){
    std::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink>> nullOstream = std::make_shared<boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink>>((boost::iostreams::null_sink()));
    std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream> nullost = std::move(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<std::ofstream>(nullOstream)); 
    this->thestreamstruct.themainWriter = nullost; 
}
```

This fails because there's no direct cast between `std::ofstream` and the boost stream.

But I can assign an `ofstream` ref as the boost null sink??

```cpp
boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::null_sink> nullout { boost::iostreams::null_sink{} };
std::ostream& out = nullout;
```

This is fine, so there must be the underlying `ofstream` somewhere? I just don't know how to get it wrapped up into a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Why `std::ofstream` instead of `std::ostream`?

Comment: If you just want to suppress `ofstream` from writing data to the output file, you can use its [inherited `rdbuf()` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) to swap in a different `basic_streambuf` that writes nothing. And then swap back in the original when you want to stop suppressing.

Comment: Look: `std::ostream& out= nullout;` that alone means you nead `ostream`, rather than `ofstream`. That's more sencible too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking some pains to get life-time correct without leaking the buffer:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6607139ffcfb13ce)**

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/null.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream_buffer.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::filesystem::path;
using sofstream = std::shared_ptr<std::ofstream>;

sofstream make_null() {
    struct both {
        boost::iostreams::stream_buffer<boost::iostreams::null_sink> b{{}};
        std::ofstream                                                ofs;
    };
    auto s = std::make_shared<both>();
    static_cast<std::ios&>(s->ofs).rdbuf(&s->b);
    return sofstream(s, &s->ofs);
}

sofstream make(path p) { return std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(p); }

int main() {
for (auto ss : { make_null(), make("test.txt") }) {
        *ss << "hello world\n";
        assert(ss->good());
        *ss << "bye world\n";
        assert(ss->good());
    }
}
```

I personally think this whole approach might be to clever by half and you should use `std::ostream&` instead of `std::ofstream&` anyways. (e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/333cc9871c5e977b)

Comment: swapped to `ostream` as it does seem like the better solution, but I've got this in the back pocket too, thanks!